# How does one read an XML file which has children with the same name as their ancestors?

Tags: c#, xml

I have trouble reading the below XML file on C# Visual web dev 2010.
As you can see Category can be a name of child as well as a parent.
When I try xmldataset.ReadXml it will come up with an error which says table Category can not be a child of itself.

Is there any other way to read this kind of XML.

A quick sample guide will be much appreciated.

```
<Categories>
  <Category id="10000000">
    <name>Clothing</name>
    <Children>
      <Category id="10010000">
        <name>Handbags & Luggage</name>
        <Children>
          <Category id="10010800">
            <name>Travel Accessories</name>
          </Category>
        </Children>
      </Category>
    </Children>
  </Category>
</Categories>
```

Comment: Read it in what way? What do you want to extract from it?

Comment: I can think of one way off the top of my head (LINQ to XML), but the real question, I think, is what are you trying to do with the data in the XML?  Are you trying to fill a DataSet with related DataTables (as you're question seems to imply), or something else?

Comment: Hi Cameron, I am basically trying to read all of the <name> fields and put them in an string array.

Comment: So, I am looking for a way to read <name> fields one by one. XPath is not going to work for this as the depth of the xml is not clear. I mean there can be a <Category> field within another <Category> within another <Category> and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think xpath will give you what you want.

```
XmlNodeList nodes = myXmlDoc.SelectNodes("//name");
```

The "//" should return all `<name>` nodes where ever they are in the xml document.
You can then do what ever you want with the list of `<name>` nodes.  For example

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Hi, This will return 0 results. any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried it? "will" suggests that you haven't tried it (future tense of some sort).  Anyway, it works for me and is correct according to this page http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp for what you are trying to do. In my example myXmlDoc is of type XmlDocument. Your question doesn't say exactly what format your xml is in. Maybe that is the issue? Post some more details of your code if you're still having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the name fields in an array, then try the following code. There might be minor syntax errors!

```
XmlDocument xd;
XmlNodeList xnl;
int i;
string[] s;

xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load(xmlFileName);
xnl = xd.SelectNodes("//Category/name");
i = 0;
s = new string[xnl.Count];
foreach(XmlNode xn in xnl)
{
    // xn will be an object of type XmlElement,
    // which exposes the value of the text it contains through the InnerText property
    s[i++] = xn.InnerText;
}

// an array of strings named 's' is available at this point.
// NB: I have omitted all manner of error checking here for clarity of code.
```

Update: I had not read your sample XML properly. I had been specifying the wrong XML path. I was specifying the path to read `<Category name="Blah">...</Category>` whereas your sample has `<Category><name>Blah></name>...</Category>`. Apologies.

Please see my comment regarding your own solution as well, though to be fair, using XmlReader is going to be a lot faster than using XmlDocument.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. xnl.Count actually return 0 result for some reason. Can you think why?

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to know,

I sorted it out with this:

```
 XmlTextReader xr = new XmlTextReader("test.xml");

            int i=0;
            string[] ss; 
            while (xr.Read())
            {
                Console.Write(xr.Name);
                if (xr.Name.ToString() == "name") { ss[i] = xr.ReadString(); i++ };
            }
```

Comment: There is a problem with this approach which is that it will get you the name attribute even for elements that are not Category.

Answer (score 0):

Using [LINQ To XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) the following code

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(@"<Categories>
  <Category id='10000000'>
    <name>Clothing</name>
    <Children>
      <Category id='10010000'>
        <name>Handbags &amp; Luggage</name>
        <Children>
          <Category id='10010800'>
            <name>Travel Accessories</name>
          </Category>
        </Children>
      </Category>
    </Children>
  </Category>
</Categories>
"));

var names = xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("name")
        .Select(n => n.Value).ToList();

names.ForEach(n => Console.WriteLine(n));
```

outputs

```
Clothing
Handbags & Luggage
Travel Accessories
```

This was tested with [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).